# Find cardinality of all subsets of $\Bbb{R}, \Bbb{Q}$ that have both the biggest and the smallest element

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be the set of all subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ that have both the biggest and the smallest element.

Let $Y$ be the set of all subsets of $\Bbb{Q}$ that have both the biggest and the smallest element.

Find cardinalities of $X,Y$.

For the first one I tried to narrow down the situation to all the subsets that have $0$ and $1$ as their min and max elements. Let $A=\{\{0,1\}\cup p \ | \ p \in P((0,1))\}$, then $|A|=2^{|(0,1)|}=2^c$, hence $c < |A| \leq |X|$. Because there is $c$ such intervals then $|X|=2^ c \cdot c$.

I don't even know how to approach the $Y$.

Comment: Show: $2^x\cdot x=2^x$ for any infinite cardinal $x.$

Comment: The same approach works for $\mathbb Q,$ since any open interval in $\mathbb Q$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb Q.$ But not your example does include single point sets. So you should really get $x+2^x\cdot x.$ But the $x+$ doesn't change anything.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for the input, although I don't see how the same approach would work for rational numbers since they are enumerable unlike real numbers. Can I even use the concept of interval in rational numbers?

Comment: We're did you use that the reals are not countable? It is not $2^c\cdot c,$ but it is $2^{|\mathbb N|}\cdot |\mathbb N|.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E=\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb Q.$ Choosing a subset of $E$ that has a max and a min amounts to choosing $a\le b$ in $E$ and then some subset of the open interval $(a,b)\subset E.$

If $a=b,$ $(a,b)=\varnothing.$ If $a<b,$ $|(a,b)|=|E|.$

The number of singletons in $E$ is $|E|.$

The number of triples $(a,b,F)$ with $a,b\in E,a<b,F\subset(a,b)$ is the number $|E|$ of elements $a$ times the number $|E|$ of elements $b>a$ times the number $2^{|(a,b)|}=2^{|E|}$ of subsets of $(a,b).$

So the number of subsets of $E$ that have a max and a min is
$$|E|+|E|^2\cdot2^{|E|}=2^{|E|}.$$

Comment: I still don't exactly see the solution there, intervals are only a subset of $X$, its elements can also be just finite enumerable sets, or mix of both. Could you also please elaborate on where the final line comes from?

Comment: @Stanley The number of subsets with your min/max property can't be more than the number $M$ of ALL subsets of $E$. So you only need show there are at least $M$ many subsets with the min/max property, which is easy since any open interval of $E$ contains a copy $E$, and so by fixing a single min/max pair $a,b$, you can find $M$ many subsets of $E$ with min $a$ and max $b$ (i.e. you don't need to worry about singletons, other min/max pairs, etc in doing the proof)

Answer (score 0):

Anne gives an answer to one possible interpretation of the question but I read it differently.  I took it as asking what cardinalities such a subset could have.

First, let's look at $\mathbb{Q}$.  $\{1\}$ qualifies so a cardinality of $1$ is possible.  Similarly, $\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$ qualifies so all finite cardinalities are possible.  The interval $[0, 1]$ qualifies so countable infinity is possible.  That's the cardinality of the whole of $\mathbb{Q}$ so we can't get any bigger.

Now, let's look at $\mathbb{R}$.  All of the previous subsets are also subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ so all of the previous answers are possible.  $[0, 1]$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ also unqualified and it has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ so that is a new possibility.  What about between the cardinalities of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$?  Well that is the [Continuum Hypothesis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis).